# Vagrant SSH - Setting up and connecting to MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, ssh, virtual-machine, vagrant

I recently installed VM and Vagrant to work with my Laravel projects. So I'm new to this. I dont have MySQL installed on my main machine. I tried to `Vagrant up` and then `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222`. Everything is fine and dandy uptil this point. I want to access MySQL and cant get access. This is what ive done:

```
mysql -u root -p (password "") -h localhost
mysql -u root -p (password "root") -h localhost
mysql -u root -h localhost
```

And even all of those without `-h localhost`. I havent set up MySQL before so keep in mind, ive never made an account to even access MySQL.

Ive searched around and ive found this:

Go to:

```
sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

And comment out: `skip-external-locking` and change this: `bind-address: 0.0.0.0`.

I then went back and restarted MySQL using `sudo service mysql restart` and tried those commands again...still no access.

Btw the error im getting is: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

However, there was something that i found interesting...
I went to `cd /etc/mysql` and I found a file named: `debian.cnf` and it had a username and password and i tried that username and password and i was logged in!!! but i dont think i was supposed to do it that way. and that password provided by that file is probably a hash of something.

Im stuck. I dont know what to do from here!

**Update**
I forgot to add: If i just provide `mysql`, I get this error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'vagrant'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Answer (score 3):

Considering you're working on a local vagrant server, I think it's okay to give this a try to rule out any other possible problems. Definitely don't do this on a production server, and ensure that your Vagrant machine is only accessible by you.

```
# fill in the blanks for root password, db name, username (local), and password
mysql -u root -p"rootpassword" -e "CREATE DATABASE db_name;
CREATE USER 'local'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
CREATE USER 'local'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'local'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'local'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"

# change bind address to allow connections from anywhere
sed -i "s/bind-address.*/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/my.cnf

# restart the sql service
sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score -1):

I run this

```
homestead up
homestead ssh
mysql -u homestead -psecret
```

for laravel 5.2 and default .env values

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```